# Robospice + Retrofit + ORMLite

Tags: java, android, ormlite, retrofit, robospice

I'm using Robospice with Retrofit ans ORMLite modules. Retrofit part working good. I have City model for Retrofit:

**City.java:**

```
public class City {
    public int city_id;
    public String name;

    @SuppressWarnings("serial")
    public static class List extends ArrayList<City> {
    }
}
```

I'm taking this model from server by GET-request:

**MyApi.java**

```
public interface MyAPI {
    @GET("/cities")
    City.List getCities();
}
```

This part works fine by calling this method:

```
getSpiceManager().execute(mRequestCity, "city", DurationInMillis.ONE_MINUTE, new ListCityRequestListener());
```

and listener:

```
public final class ListCityRequestListener implements RequestListener<City.List> {

    @Override
    public void onRequestFailure(SpiceException spiceException) {
        Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "failure", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestSuccess(final City.List result) {
        Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        updateCities(result);
    }
}
```

At this time i want to download city list once from server and store this list into sqlitedb by ORMLite module. I've created ORMLite model:

**City.java**

```
@DatabaseTable(tableName = "city")
public class City {
    public final static String DB_CITY_ID_FIELD_NAME = "id";
    public final static String DB_CITY_NAME_FIELD_NAME = "name";

    @DatabaseField(canBeNull =  false, dataType = DataType.INTEGER, columnName = DB_CITY_ID_FIELD_NAME)
    int id;

    @DatabaseField(canBeNull = false, dataType = DataType.STRING, columnName = DB_CITY_NAME_FIELD_NAME)
    private String name;

    public City() {

    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        sb.append("id = ").append(id);
        sb.append(", ").append("name = ").append(name);

        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

My **RetrofitSpiceService.java** looks like this:

```
public class RetrofitSpiceService extends RetrofitGsonSpiceService {

    private final static String BASE_URL = "http://example.com/api/v1";
    private final static UserFunctions userFunctions = new UserFunctions();

    @Override
    public CacheManager createCacheManager(Application application) throws CacheCreationException {
        CacheManager cacheManager = new CacheManager();
        List< Class< ? >> classCollection = new ArrayList< Class< ? >>();

        // add persisted classes to class collection
        classCollection.add( City.class );

        // init
        RoboSpiceDatabaseHelper databaseHelper = new RoboSpiceDatabaseHelper( application, "sample_database.db", 1 );
        InDatabaseObjectPersisterFactory inDatabaseObjectPersisterFactory = new InDatabaseObjectPersisterFactory( application, databaseHelper, classCollection );
        cacheManager.addPersister( inDatabaseObjectPersisterFactory );

        return cacheManager;
    }

    @Override
    protected Builder createRestAdapterBuilder() {
        Builder mBuilder = super.createRestAdapterBuilder();

        mBuilder.setRequestInterceptor(new RequestInterceptor() {
            @Override
            public void intercept(RequestFacade request) {
                if (userFunctions.isUserLoggedIn()) {
                    request.addHeader("Authorization", userFunctions.getToken());
                }
            }
        });

        return mBuilder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        addRetrofitInterface(MyAPI.class);
    }

    @Override
    protected String getServerUrl() {
        return BASE_URL;
    }
}
```

I can't understand how can i store and read data from my **City** database? How do i need to change RetrofitSpiceService? I want download data by **Retrofit** and store it to database by **ORMLite**. My CacheManager is correct, i.e. will work properly? Maybe I misunderstand how the module **Robospice-ORMLite** works?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you make execute() call with cache key and duration Robospice will store your response into database.

```
getSpiceManager().execute(mRequestCity, "city", DurationInMillis.ONE_MINUTE, new ListCityRequestListener());
```

All following requests during one minute will get data from this cache, and then it makes network call. If you want to get data only from cache take a look on   [getSpiceManager().getFromCache()](http://stephanenicolas.github.io/robospice/site/latest/apidocs/com/octo/android/robospice/SpiceManager.html#getFromCache(java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.Object,%20long,%20com.octo.android.robospice.request.listener.RequestListener)) method. I think it's what you are looking for.

Comment: It means that I can use only cache, without sqlite ? I think this wouldn't work when user close and open app again. In future I want to get timestamp that indicates when City table changed on server. I'll check this time and if it greater than my timestamp in sqlite I will download data from server again. Can u give some example how to use Retrofit & ormlite together? Network requests needed only in Retrofit module.

Comment: 1. Cache of Robospice use ORMLite when you pass it in createCacheManager(). And data will still be in cache if you forceclose application and open it again.
2. You need something like If-Modified-Since/Last-Modified cache implementation. So if data wasn't modified server returns 304.
Please, take a look on Robospice documentation it covers a lot of questions how it works.